# get common lines from two text files

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I've got two files.

The first (`file1`) is like so:
(there is always a headerline before a 'text'line)

```
>random header name1
wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
>random header 2
someotherline
...
```

The other file (`file2`) is a modifed file of `file1` like: 
(the header have been removed and the lines are shuffled, a new header has been added)

```
>name
someotherline
wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
```

Each line (without the header) of `file1` occurs in `file2`. 
The order of lines in `file2` differs from `file1`. 
Both files should stay in the order they are.

Each line in `file2`

Output should be something alike:
(header of `file2` can be ignored)

```
>random header 2
>random header name1
```

Has anybody a clue, how to do so?

Best regards

Comment: I assure you, they can be sorted.

Comment: What do you mean: they can't be sorted? Are they too big? Or is it stream, and not a file itself? It's important, because the reason for non-sortability might limit your options. Generally, as I understand - you want to find lines that are unique in both of the files. This can be usually done by: `cat files* | sort | uniq -u`

Comment: @depesz: To avoid useless pipe snakes use `sort files*|uniq -u`.

Comment: @TrueY - well, ok. I tend to use "cat" anyway, because it's simpler to reuse such line for other tasks, and cat overhead is negligible, but if that will make you happy - I'll use your, cat-less, version :)

Comment: I assume the second `file1 looks like this:` should refer to `file2`, doesn't it? What about `>name` in file2? It does not need to be shown in the output?

Comment: i updated my question, since it wasn't clear enough, i am sorry about it. @TrueY yes, the `>name` of `file2` can be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed '/^[>]/N;s#\(.*\)\n\(.*\)#/\2/s/.*/\1/p#' file1|sed -nf - file2
>random header 2
>random header name1
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the clarification that the files should stay the same, just use:

```
sort file1 file2 file2 | uniq -u
```

and you're done.

Alternatively, if the files are big, so that sorting of (file1+file2+file2) is too much of a burden, you can use this:

```
comm -23 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
```

Which will just sort each file (the file on disk will be kept the way it is, it will not be modified), and then print lines which exist in file1, but not in file2.

Example:

```
=$ cat file1 
some header
abc
cdf
efg
other header

=$ cat file2 
file2 header
cdf
file2 header part2
efg
abc

=$ comm -23 <( sort file1 ) <( sort file2 )
other header
some header
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to print the respective header from file1 corresponding to each element of file2.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat file2 | 
while read line; do 
    grep -B 1 "$line" file1 | head -n1
done
```

`grep -B 1` will print one line before match. We can cut the first line by head.
This might be called a hack. (But I'm still a beginner).

file1:

> >random header name1
>   wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
>   >random header 2
>   someotherline

file2:

> someotherline
>   wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson

Output:

> >random header 2
>   >random header name1

Also understand this solution as pointed out by depesz is slow.

Comment: This approach will be rather slow, as it will have to grep file2 N times, where N is number of rows in file2. Plus, I'm not sure if this is what OP wanted, but I leave it for him to judge, since I'm not sure I understand his description either.

Comment: @mohit Thank you a lot! This is pretty close to what i searched for! What do i do, if the header is a line ahead and not in the same line?