# Line after match of two files

Tags: perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a similar problem like [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361450/get-common-lines-from-two-text-files).

This time i have a `header` file looking like:

```
>random header 2
>random header name1
```

and my `basefile`

```
>random header name1
wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
>random header 2
someotherline
```

now the aim is, to have the following output:

> someotherline
>
> wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson

So i want the line after the match from the `basefile`. (and only this one, not the header)

Important with this, it shall keep the order of `header`.

Sort won't work, since it will keep alphabetic order and this just shouldn't happen.

I couldn't figure out, how grep could compare two files and just gives the line after match :/

Comment: you can modify `sort`. Just use something like `sort _sort_function ...` [take a look here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reads `basefile` into `%h` hash, and later follows key order specified in `header` file,

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ open $F,pop or die $!; %h=<$F> } print $h{$_}' header basefile
```

Comment: @EdMorton this one looks pretty decent actually :)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job for you:

```
awk 'FNR==NR
    {
        a[$0]=FNR;i=FNR;next
    }
    ($0 in a)
    {
        t=$0;
        getline;b[a[t]]=$0
    }
    END
    {
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)print b[k]
    }'  head base
```

Comment: This won't keep the order of `header`!

Comment: The `BEGIN{i=0}` is redundant.

Comment: `i` is redundant, just loop to NR-FNR in the END. If you're considering using `getline` make sure you read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and fully understand it and can live with all the caveats. And then don't use it that way. I do like the idea though, +1 for that.

Comment: Remember to put your opening curly braces on the same line as the condition - as written every action block will be executed for every line, not just those that match the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
awk '
   { recs[NR] = $0 }  # store the header lines in 1->(NR-FNR) and the basefile lines in ((NR-FNR)+1)->NR
   END {
       for (hdrNr=1; hdrNr<=(NR-FNR); hdrNr++) {
           hdr = recs[hdrNr]
           for (lineNr=(NR-FNR)+1; lineNr<=NR; lineNr++) {
               line = recs[lineNr]
               if (line == hdr) {
                   print recs[lineNr+1]
               }
           }
       }
   }
' header basefile
```

Following up on @Vijays idea of just storing the matching lines in an array indexed by the order the headers are read in, here's how you'd do that without getline, without unnecessary variables, with meaningful variable names, and without printing blank lines for every unmatched header:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { hdr2nr[$0] = FNR; next }
    hdrNr   { hdrNr2line[hdrNr] = $0 }
    { hdrNr = hdr2nr[$0] }
    END {
        for(hdrNr=1; hdrNr<=(NR-FNR); hdrNr++)
            if (hdrNr in hdrNr2line)
                print hdrNr2line[hdrNr]
    }
'  header basefile
```

That assumes a given header can only appear once in basefile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this bash one-liner:

```
while read line; do match=$(sed -n "/$line/{ n;p}" basefile); echo $match; done < 'header'
```

This will work, when your basefile always have one line definition for corresponding header.

header:

```
sat:~# cat header
>random header 2
>random header name1
```

basefile:

```
 sat:~# cat basefile 
 >random header name1 
 wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
 >random header 2 
 someotherline
```

Output:

```
 sat:~# while read line; do match=$(sed -n "/$line/{ n;p}" basefile);echo $match; done < 'header' 
 someotherline
 wonderfulstringwhatsoevergoeson
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)/s|^\1$|\2|/' base_file | sed -f - header_file
```

Turn the `base_file` into a `sed` script and run it against the `header_file`.